# Creating an event in a custom class that triggers when a checkbox is checked on the main form (simulation of logic gates)

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, delegates, event-handling

I want  to simulate a XOR-gate for example, by using check boxes or radio buttons as input and outputs. I want to create an event in a custom class that triggers when a input check box is checked or unchecked.

this is the custom class that I created

```
class TriggeringGates
{
    public delegate void Triggering(TriggeringGates gate, EventArgs e);
    public event Triggering Status;

    bool A, B, X;

    public TriggeringGates()
    {
        A = true;
        B = true;
        X = false;
    }

    public bool InputA
    {
        get { return A; }
        set
        {
            A = value;
             X = (A & !B | B & !A);
             Status(this, new EventArgs());  
        }
    }

    public bool InputB
    {
        get { return B; }
        set
        {
            B = value;
            X = (A & !B | B & !A);
            Status(this, new EventArgs());   
        }
    }

    public bool OutputX
    {
        get { return X; }
        set { }
    }
```

this is the main form... I have no idea how to link the event to this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TriggeringGates trigger;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        trigger = new TriggeringGates();
        trigger.Status += new TriggeringGates.Triggering(trigger_Status);
    }

    void trigger_Status(object gate, EventArgs e)
    {
        trigger.InputA = checkBox1.Checked;
        trigger.InputB = checkBox2.Checked;
        trigger.OutputX = checkBox3.Checked;
    }


    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your current code and we'll try to help you from there.

Comment: I have added my code

Answer (score 0):

So this is could be your answer.
Event class

```
public class CustomEvent : EventArgs
{
    public CustomEvent(bool stat)
    {
        Stat = stat;
    }
    public bool Stat { get; set; }
}
```

Your business logic

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(Gates gate, CustomEvent e);
public class Gates
{
    public event MyEventHandler OnStatusChanged;

    bool A, B, X;

    public Gates()
    {
        A = true;
        B = true;
        X = false;
    }

    public bool InputA
    {
        get { return A; }
        set
        {
            A = value;
            X = (A & !B | B & !A);
            if(OnStatusChanged!=null)
                OnStatusChanged(this, new CustomEvent(X));
        }
    }

    public bool InputB
    {
        get { return B; }
        set
        {
            B = value;
            X = (A & !B | B & !A);
            if (OnStatusChanged != null) 
                OnStatusChanged(this, new CustomEvent(X));
        }
    }

    public bool OutputX
    {
        get { return X; }
        set { X = value; }
    }
}
```

Main form

```
    private Gates _gate;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _gate = new Gates();
        _gate.OnStatusChanged += gate_OnStatusChanged; //setup event handler
        checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
        checkBox2.CheckedChanged += checkBox2_CheckedChanged;
        checkBox3.Enabled = false;
    }

    void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _gate.InputA = checkBox2.Checked;
    }

    void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _gate.InputB = checkBox1.Checked;
    }

    void gate_OnStatusChanged(Gates gates, CustomEvent e)
    {
        checkBox3.Checked = e.Stat;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand 100%

Comment: I edited my post with a link to more information about events.

Comment: I am even more confused than I was before... can you please edit my code with what I am missing.

Comment: Why you don't use the built in checkbox event checkedchanged?

Comment: We have to create our own event and delegate and link it to checkboxes or radiobuttons

Comment: Edited my post. You will have to use checked changed event. To get the value from your checkboxes. Unless you are polling the checkboxes for their values, your main thread will be halted then. But you can generated an event when some conditions are met like I do.